# Snow Leopard Server in Fusion VM: installation keeps failing

Tags: snow-leopard, install, vmware

I’m trying to install Snow Leopard Server 10.6.3, which I just purchased from Apple (so it’s not tied to any hardware), into a VMWare Fusion 5.x VM, and the install keeps failing.

At first I was getting “ERROR_DOWNLOAD_FAILED” as the reason, so I disabled the network adapter for the VM to see what happened.  At that point, it failed with the even more helpful “support files could not be installed”.  That’s it; it didn’t bother to tell me which support files, just that they couldn’t be installed.  When I tried again, it went back to “ERROR_DOWNLOAD_FAILED”.  I turned the network adapter back on, and failed the same way.

I’m using the default install options, which should require a little under 12GB, and the VM’s HD has 43GB available.  The machine I’m running the VM on is a MacBook Pro (i7) running OS X 10.8.

Any insights are appreciated!

**EDIT**: see my answer below for the resolution, which required two steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a link that might help: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/457351

You have Server, so that should be OK, try ripping it into a disk image (if you haven't already done so) and see if it will work with that instead.

I only have personal experience with Parallels, so I can't try it myself.

Comment: Creating a DMG now; I’ll report back with results.  Thanks for the leads!

Comment: Followup: the DMG approach definitely got me further, but then I ran into a CPU problem.  Overcame that, looks like, but I’m still updating.  I’ll write up everything once I’m finished!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was a confluence of two things: trying to install from physical media, and CPU incompatibility.  Here’s how I got past it:

First, I created a disk image (.dmg) of the install disc, as per BoxOfSnoo’s answer.  The thread s/he linked to led me to the VMWare Community article [Creating a disc image from physical Mac OS X install media](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-23659), which I used to get me past the “ERROR_DOWNLOAD_FAILED” barrier.

With that resolved, however, I immediately ran into the error “The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system.”  Googling that led me to the VMWare KB article [Installing OS X Snow Leopard Server on an i5- or i7-based Macbook Pro fails with the error: The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system (1026103)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026103), which informed me that OS X 10.6.3—the version that Apple ships you when you order it—is not compatible with i7 (and other) Macs.

I used the .vmx editing solution shown in that article to mask the CPU, which let me finish the installation.  That done, I ran Software Update in the VM to update to 10.6.8, which can handle i7 (etc.) CPUs.  Then I shut down the VM, removed the CPU-masking line I’d added to the .vmx file, and launched the VM.  Success!