# Snow Leopard Server 10.6.8 under Fusion 7.1.3 on Sierra 10.12.2

Tags: snow-leopard, virtualization, vmware, osx-server

I have seen posts like [Snow Leopard Server in Fusion VM: installation keeps failing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120004/snow-leopard-server-in-fusion-vm-installation-keeps-failing) on how to install Snow Leopard Server 10.6.**8** on a VMware VM, but as best I can tell, the recommended solution is to create a .dmg file from the disk, and then do one of several things, including install Snow Leopard 10.6.4 or more recent. I also tried adding 
`cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:1010:0101"` to the .vmx file without noted difference.

The behavior I have experienced both attempting to install directly from media, and attempting to install from a .dmg file created from that media per [Snow Leopard Server in Fusion VM: installation keeps failing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120004/snow-leopard-server-in-fusion-vm-installation-keeps-failing)'s first response, is that it seems to start booting or installing, asks which language to use to install, and then gives a dialogue that says, 'Mac OS X can't be installed on this computer. If you want to restore your system from a Time Machine backup, click "Restore From Backup."', with buttons saying 'Restore From Backup' and 'Restart'.

Is there a current HOWTO to install OSX Server 10.6.8 under Fusion 7.1.2 on 10.12.2?

Thanks,

Comment: I have no problem installing Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server 10.6.3 using VMware Fusion 7.1.2 under OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5 using an image made from the Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server 10.6.3 DVD using Disk Utility. As far as I know Apple latest release of Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server 10.6 on DVD was Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server 10.6.3 not Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server 10.6.8, so I have no way to test installing Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server 10.6.8 using VMware Fusion 7.1.2 under OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5 or macOS Sierra 10.12.2.

Comment: I seriously doubt there is a specific how to to install Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server 10.6.8 under Fusion 7.1.2 on macOS Sierra 10.12.2. VMware also has their own discussion forum for VMware Fusion, so you might want to check over there and post your question there too.

Answer (score 1):

I purchased a Mac Mini version that will only install to a Mac Mini, and even there it was unlikely. So I purchased instead an unlimited version. I expect and hope that it will work along the lines @user3439894 suggests.

Comment: What I used was Mac OS X Server v10.6 Snow Leopard - Unlimited Client License $19.99, which was 10.6.3 and I had to order it by phone from Apple. If this is what you ordered then it should work for you as it did for me and many others I know who purchased it and used the same thing in a virtual machine.